# pass function argument to cursor in oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, oracle10g

I am getting an error while passing function argument to the cursor. Here is the Below example

Create OR Replace FUNCTION UPD_TAB(ID_VAL IN OUT VARCHAR2,SRC_COLUMN IN OUT  VARCHAR2,DEST_COLUMN IN OUT VARCHAR2,OWNER_TAB IN OUT VARCHAR2,SRC_TAB IN OUT VARCHAR2,DEST_TAB IN OUT VARCHAR2)
RETURN VARCHAR2
IS

SRC_COL VARCHAR2(30) := SRC_COLUMN;
     DEST_COL VARCHAR2(20) := DEST_COLUMN;
     ID_VALUE VARCHAR2(20) := ID_VAL;
     SRC_TABLE VARCHAR(20) := SRC_TAB;
     DEST_TABLE VARCHAR(20) := DEST_TAB;
     TAB1 VARCHAR2(40) := OWNER_TAB||'.'||SRC_TAB;
     TAB2 VARCHAR2(40) := OWNER_TAB||'.'||DEST_TAB;
 CURSOR RET_VAL
        IS
        SELECT C1.SRC_COL,C2.DEST_COL 
                  FROM ***TAB1 C1,TAB2 C2***
          WHERE C1.SRC_COL=C2.DEST_COL 
                    AND C1.ID=ID_VALUE;

Here in the above example when pass pass the actual database values Schemaname.Tablename 
eg. grany.Booking . It output the results but when i pass the variable having value TAB1 and TAB2. It shows the following error

PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist 
22/11    PL/SQL: Statement ignored

i searched a lot but didn't find the solution
I know what error is trying to say but i dont know how to fix the solution for this one.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Google "Oracle dynamic SQL".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Static cursors cannot obtain table and column names from variables. One way to get around this is to build the query in a VARCHAR2 variable and then open a generic cursor (SYS_REFCURSOR type, defined in package SYS.STANDARD) for the query string:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION UPD_TAB(ID_VAL      IN OUT VARCHAR2,
                                   SRC_COLUMN  IN OUT VARCHAR2,
                                   DEST_COLUMN IN OUT VARCHAR2,
                                   OWNER_TAB   IN OUT VARCHAR2,
                                   SRC_TAB     IN OUT VARCHAR2,
                                   DEST_TAB    IN OUT VARCHAR2)
  RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
  SRC_COL     VARCHAR2(30) := SRC_COLUMN;
  DEST_COL    VARCHAR2(20) := DEST_COLUMN;
  ID_VALUE    VARCHAR2(20) := ID_VAL;
  SRC_TABLE   VARCHAR2(20) := SRC_TAB;
  DEST_TABLE  VARCHAR2(20) := DEST_TAB;
  TAB1        VARCHAR2(40) := OWNER_TAB||'.'||SRC_TAB;
  TAB2        VARCHAR2(40) := OWNER_TAB||'.'||DEST_TAB;

  vVAL1       VARCHAR2(2000);
  vVAL2       VARCHAR2(2000);

  strCursor   VARCHAR2(32767) :=
     'SELECT C1.' || SRC_COL ||
           ',C2.' || DEST_COL ||
       'FROM ' || TAB1 || ' C1, ' ||
                  TAB2 || ' C2 ' ||
       'WHERE C1.' || SRC_COL || '=C2.' || DEST_COL || ' AND ' ||
             'C1.ID=' || ID_VALUE;

  csr         SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
  OPEN csr FOR strCursor;

  LOOP
    FETCH csr
      INTO vVAL1, vVAL2;

    EXIT WHEN csr%NOTFOUND;

    -- Do something useful with values fetched from cursor;
  END LOOP;

  CLOSE csr;
END UPD_TAB;
```

Share and enjoy.